# How to display Cosmos DB data on a website

Tags: azure, nosql, azure-web-app-service, azure-cosmosdb

I have a Cosmos DB in which userdata is stored and partitioned by userID. I save this data to the DB with a chatbot built with MS Botframework v4.

I access the DB in the same way it is presented in this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-persist-user-inputs?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript).

The object per user looks something like this:

```
{
    "id": "3213",
    "realId": "3213",
    "document": {
        "name": "frank",
        "age": 18,
        "gender": "weiblich",
        "riskAssessmentComplete": true,
        "riskDescription": "höchst risikoliebend",
        "order": [
            "1",
            "0",
            "2"
        ],
        "payout": "6,50€"
    },
    "_rid": "YsI4AMvVJ9cRAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/YsI4AA==/colls/YsI4AMvVJ9c=/docs/YsI4AMvVJ9cRAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"00007d7e-0000-0000-0000-5c89b6600000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1552528992
}
```

What I wanna do now is use a website to display a specific value ("payout"). How can I access the database from a website? Unfortunately, I didn't find a tutorial on how to access cosmos DB from a website. Since I use the state management and storage object the Botframework provides, I don't know how to accomplish this without them.

Comment: Not sure what you're specifically asking. Accessing Cosmos DB would be similar to accessing any other database. What specific issue are you running into? Please edit your question accordingly. Right now, this is fairly broad (and off-topic).

Comment: Sorry for being too broad. I hope I could clarify a few things. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Did you try to parse the object to json, then read the value.

Comment: Cosmos DB support CORS now, you can use either node.js SDK or REST api talk to Cosmos DB directly from a website

Answer (score 0):

You can use the REST APIs or C# to access the content and display it on the given web page.  There are some deep samples and tutorials available such as:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-dotnet-samples